# Retrieving a list from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to retrieve a list of object from Firebase.
This is the structure of database:
[image]

I have tried this:

```
this.db.object('/users/'+this.userId+'/movies-favourited/').snapshotChanges().subscribe(data=>{
      this.favouriteList = data.payload.val()
});
```

I am getting null from this query. What am I missing??

P.S. : This is what I am getting in console with data.payload:

```
Object { _database: {…}, _delegate: {…} }
​
_database: Object { _delegate: {…}, app: {…}, INTERNAL: {…} }
​​
INTERNAL: Object { delete: delete()
 }
​​
_delegate: Object { _repoInternal: {…}, type: "database", _instanceStarted: true, … }
​​
app: Object { isDeleted_: false, name_: "[DEFAULT]", automaticDataCollectionEnabled_: false, … }
​​
<prototype>: Object { useEmulator: useEmulator(host, port, options), ref: ref(path), refFromURL: refFromURL(url)
, … }
​
_delegate: Object { _node: {…}, ref: {…}, _index: {} }
​​
_index: Object {  }
​​
_node: Object { children_: {…}, priorityNode_: null, indexMap_: {…}, … }
​​
ref: Object { _repo: {…}, _path: {…}, _orderByCalled: false, … }
​​
<prototype>: Object { child: child(path), exists: exists(), exportVal: exportVal()
, … }
​
<prototype>: Object { val: val(), exportVal: exportVal(), toJSON: toJSON(), … }
```

Comment: Can you please `console.log(this.userId)` and check if it is valid?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes , I am getting the correct id. I tested it.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data.payload.val())` ? The object seems to be a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot).

Comment: Yes ,  its giving null in console.

Comment: Can you please `console.log(\`/users/${this.userId}/movies-favourited\`)` and share the response just to confirm?

Comment: ````/users/jIyHHBAMQdPSP6paGdkkUhhXL1s2/movies-favourited```` is the response I get

Comment: Have you tried using `db.list()` instead of `db.object()` as in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md) ?

Comment: I had tried it , but it was giving me an empty array.

Comment: Depends where you do the list.  On the movies-favourited node for instance, you would get the array there, with all the objects underneath, and likely need to define your classes to handle this.  You could forEach through the results, but need to go down a level (record.MovieId) or similar